# submit form into new window > displays pdf > parent loses child window reference

Tags: javascript, window.open, window.onunload

I have the following code onClick of a button

```
$('#someForm').attr("target", "formresult");

.......

winPop = window.open("", 'formresult', 'allthesettingshereblablah');

.......

$('#someForm').submit();
```

everything works and a new pdf is displayed in the popup window.

I want to put in a logic like if there is already a popup open, ignore the button click... If I don't do submit, I can do winPop.closed check and it will have the correct reference.

BUT, if I have the submit(), the reference is lost...winPop.closed no longer works.

I know the reference is changed because if I put in

```
winPop.onbeforeunload = function() {
alert('i am closing');         
};
```

the I am closing alert is displayed right before the pdf displays, which means that the original winPop is unloaded and I no longer have that reference.

What is the proper flow/way I should do this?

Basically I need click generate button from parent window >> submit form and opens pdf in child window >> If I click generate button from parent window again, it should ignore the click when child window is open.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you're trying to do correctly, you simply can check whether popup window is open before trying to open a new one.
So something like this:

```
if (winPop ) {
winPop.focus();
    }else{
 winPop = window.open("", 'formresult', 'allthesettingshereblablah');
}
```

This should focus on poup window if there's one open already. Otherwise new one is opened.

Comment: the issue is that winPop reference is not correct after the pdf launches.